# error when trying to debug an external process using notepad++ and csscript

Tags: c#, debugging, notepad++, remote-debugging, cs-script

For my company I am tasked with finding a way to debug external processes and 'cs scripts'.

The thing i'm trying to achieve is letting project engineers (who do not have visual studio) debug the scripts they write.
We have quite a neat system where a project engineer can write a simple script for adding a bit more functionality to our main program (turning on lights on special input) (it's used a lot to inteface between custom I/O of customers and our software.)

So I thought a good point to start is checking out the csscript plugin for notepad++, For building a simple script (if it has a static void main) it is more than great, it is awesome. However I wanted to try the "Debug external process" feature and the moment i click on it i get this error:

```
************** Tekst van uitzondering **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at CSScriptNpp.DebugExternal.<GetProcessList>d__11.MoveNext()
   at CSScriptNpp.DebugExternal.Repopulete(Boolean refetch)
   at CSScriptNpp.DebugExternal.<Reload>b__8_0()


************** Loaded assembly's **************
mscorlib
    Assembly-version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-version: 4.6.1076.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
CSScriptNpp
    Assembly-version: 1.0.46.0
    Win32-version: 1.0.46.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Notepad++/plugins/CSScriptNpp.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly-version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-version: 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly-version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-version: 4.6.1075.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly-version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32-version: 4.6.1068.2 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
CSScriptIntellisense
    Assembly-version: 1.0.14.0
    Win32-version: 1.0.14.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Notepad++/plugins/CSScriptNpp/CSScriptIntellisense.dll
----------------------------------------
```

And quite frankly i have no idea what to do because all i do is:
open notepad++ -> plugins -> csscript -> Debug external process.

any that has any experience with this? or knows a better way?

Comment: did you save the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by uninstalling notepad++ and removing all the plugins and leftover files/folders in `Program Files (x86)\Notepad++`

after that i reinstalled npp and downloaded the plugin again, now it works.